# How to redirect all requests for a site's sub-director(ies) to a specific web document

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site with many web documents in a sub-directory and sub-directories.

I want all of them to resolve to a single new landing page.

Note: my `.htaccess` file is in the doc root

Example:

`http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/*` --> `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php`

This needs to include `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/another-sub-directory/*` --> `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php`

This should not apply to `http://mysite.example.com/any-other-sub-directory/*` ... only `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/*`

I've tried:

```
# these do not work
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sub-directory/$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sub-directory/(.+)$ /index.php [L]

# these do not work either
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.example\.com\/sub-directory\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php [R=302,NC,L]
```

I need a redirect rule vs. a pure re-write rule for both SEO and my users's browser bookmark purposes. Therefore, if anyone tries to visit `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/*` I want them redirected to `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php` and I want them to see `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php` as the browser URL. If they request any other web page in the site outside of `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/*`, I want them to see the page they request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single rule in site root .htaccess should work for all the dub directories.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(sub-directory)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

You have to make sure that:

1. There is no .htaccess in sub directories
2. Above rule is the only rule in site root .htaccess

Comment: But I do not want to redirect `http://mysite.example.com/different-directory/` only `http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory*/`

Comment: and my .htaccess file is in the doc root

Comment: I want a redirect for SEO pruposes

Comment: so where do you define/specify the `/sub-directory/*` part @anubhava?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure you are following what I want to accomplish here @anubhava

Comment: Ok, I tried it and the rewrite did this `http://mysite.example.com/htdocs/live/abcd/htdocs/index.php` and the broser reported `This page isn’t working

mysite.example.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: Nope...the rewrite did this `http://mysite.example.com/htdocs/live/abcd/htdocs/index.php`

Comment: Tried in a fresh browser session and it does not work on my machine...still getting 404 PNF `http://mysite.example.com/htdocs/live/abcd/htdocs/index.php`

Comment: If you're getting `htdocs` then either it is old cache or you didn't apply leading slash in target as `/$1/index.php` instead of `$1/index.php`

Comment: I tweaked it and got it to work using this `RewriteRule ^(sub-directory)/(.+)$ http://mysite.example.com/sub-directory/index.php [L,R=302]`. Thanks @anubhava !!